# Adding plus sign to create in a quick way a task under boards -> sprints -> backlog in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

In our scrum process, we've observed an issue where a user is unable to create a task or a bug under "Boards" -> "Sprints" -> "Backlog" within the "Unparented Item" section.

For this particular user, it displays as "Unparented Item," but they do not see the plus sign to add a new item. However, for other users, it simply shows as "Unparented," and they can see the plus sign to create new tasks or bugs.

Here we see without the plus sign

[image]

Here is how it should look.

[image]

I tried to play with the permissions but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my tests, the affected user cannot see the plus sign because he has turned on the preview feature "New Boards Hubs". To check “New Boards Hubs”, please go to Users Settings -> Preview features.
[image]

As a workaround, you can turn off the “New Boards Hubs” temporarily. But if you turn it off, you won't be able to use some new features. It's suggested that you could report this issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Not, it should not. Unparented work items are not a valid situation. If you want to add a new unparented add it in the Work Items section:

[image]